# How to catch errors from a chain of async functions of a third party library?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, async-await

I need to catch an error from a third party library.

```
(async () => {

    try {
        var response = await func_1();
        console.log("should not show this");
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("should show this", err);
    }

    async function func_1() {
        func_2();
    }

    async function func_2() {
        func_N();
    }

    async function func_N() {
        throw new Error("oops");
    }
    
})();
```

So I need to catch func_N error in try catch but becuase **func_N** is **async** and it's called by some functions without **await** the try catch doesn't catch the error.

So is there any way to do this?

Comment: Your not either returning your functions or awaiting them, you have dangling promises.   `try / catch` works fine with `async / await`.  eg. don't break the chain `return func_2();` or `await func_2()`..  Same for `func_N` of course

Comment: @Keith Hi. Tnx for your comment. Actually only the try catch is my code. the func_1, func_2, ... , func_N is for third party library and that's the problem. I can't change the library code because It takes a long time.

Comment: @DavoodTaheri It's a bug in the third party library. Make them fix it, or fork it, or don't use that library, or don't call it when `func_N` will error.

Comment: A bit dirty, but you could maybe patch the bad code, but ideally the 3rd party should fix there code.

Comment: Actually it's puppeteer. and when I call page.goto() function, sometimes it throw this error and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: With pupperteer, patching should be very simple using -> https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.setrequestinterception/

Comment: That didn't solve my problem but I solved it by using process.on("uncaughtException") for now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> func_N is `async` and it's called by some functions without `await`
> <sub>*(and without `return`)*</sub>

Then they need to fix that. There's nothing you can do about this otherwise.

Comment: Actually only the try catch is my code. the func_1, func_2, ... , func_N is for third party library and that's the problem. I can't change the library code because It takes a long time.

Comment: I wrote that **they** need to fix it, yes, not that *you* need to fix it.

Comment: So there isn't any way to do this without changing the library codes?

Comment: It's hard to tell if you don't show the real code, but generally yes.

Comment: I checked their codes and I figured out somewhere they call a function in an event callback and that cause the error. Somthing like throwing error from inside addEvenetListener callback. So I solved my problem by using process.on("uncaughtException") for now. Thank you for your help.